# Kotlin 1.3.0 not working with kotlin-stdlib

Tags: android, kotlin

I wanted to update the version of my kotlin plugin to 1.3.10. This is what looks like my build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.10'
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
                 }
}
```

Then i want to define a variable for my kotlin-stdlib :

```
ext.kotlinDependency = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
```

But it does not work for this last line, I have always done this way and it worked well for the 1.2.61 version. Should i just wait before updating the version for the last one ?

Comment: Try using `jdk7` instead of `jre7`

Comment: thanks, worked well. Do you have any explication maybe ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the [Kotlin 1.3 compatibility guide](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compatibility-guide-13.html#discontinued-deprecated-artifacts-in-the-compiler-distribution) says,`kotlin-stdlib-jre7` is a deprecated artifact name which has been removed in Kotlin 1.3. `kotlin-stdlib-jdk7` is the replacement to be used.